# Setting label for tooltip in flot based on x-axis value

Tags: jquery, flot, flot.tooltip

I have a line graph using flot. I want the tooltip to show the x-axis and y-axis values.

I am trying:

```
content: "Orders <b>%y</b> for <span>%x</span>",
```

But this shows "Orders 100 for 0" for the first point, "Orders 100 for 1" for the second and so on.

If I use:

```
content: "Orders <b>%y</b> for <span>"+chartData.axis[0][1]+"</span>",
```

Then this correctly shows the x-axis value for the first point.

But this doesn't work:

```
content: "Orders <b>%y</b> for <span>"+chartData.axis[%x][1]+"</span>",
```

It gives me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
```

How can I reference the value of %x within chartData.axis ?

Comment: For the first point on the graph %x = 0, for the second %x = 1. And so on

Comment: What tooltip plugin are you using?

Comment: Have you tried it with `chartData.axis[x][1]` (without the `%`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you would be better served using the `function` callback of the `content` property instead of the string formatting (and I'm guessing that's where you are going and asked your next [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356005/using-function-to-create-dynamic-response)).

```
 tooltip: true,
   tooltipOpts: {
       content: function(label, xval, yval, flotItem){
           return "Orders <b>"+yval+"</b> for <span>"+chartData.axis[xval][2]+"</span>"
       },
       shifts: {
         x: -30,
         y: -50
       }
  }
```

Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4wP4/).

Comment: i get chartData undefined