# Using function() to create dynamic response

Tags: jquery, flot

The following code works:

```
tooltipOpts: {
  content: "%s : %y",
  shifts: {
  x: -30,
  y: -50
  }
}
```

I am trying to show some dynamically calculated data in "content" so am trying to use a function. Even my most basic example isn't working, I get error shown below:

```
 tooltipOpts: {
   content: function() {
     return "%s : %y";
   },
   shifts: {
     x: -30,
     y: -50
   }
 }


Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    return "%s : %y";
} has no method 'replace'
```

Comment: Also tag with the plugin you're using.

Comment: Are you using an additional tooltip plugin? That doesn't look like default flot tooltips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you are using the [tooltip plugin](https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip) from here.  I've coded up a fiddle example, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XEha9/1/),  that uses the `function` format of the `content` property.  Note that your callback signature it incorrect:

```
content: function(label, xval, yval, flotItem){ // expects to pass these arguments
    return "%s : %y";
},
```

But even without those arguments, I couldn't reproduce your error.